# Programatically preset a standard value for Regular Price

Tags: backend, magento2, price, custom-backend

In the Magento 2 backend, when adding a new product, the Regular Price is empty. As a hint to my webmaster, I want the Regular Price to be preset with a certain value.

I was hoping this could simply be done with, for instance, a Custom Aattribute or a System Value setting, but apparantly that's not the case.

In the M2 backend, in the Add Product section, I come across socalled "Mask". Would that be the way to go? Does a Mask for Regular Price exists?

I tried to find my way through config.xml and system.xml. But it is not clear to me how I could to achieve what I want using this technique in Magento 2.

If there is no other (rather simple) way, I would consider changing the EAV_attribute table (row: default_value) in the Magento database, but I don't think that is the proper way of doing it.

So I am stuck. It looks like I am searching with the wrong keywords, because nowhere anything shows up that relates to what I want.

Anybody out there who could get me on track?